# Cardinality of a subset of an ordinal

Tags: logic, set-theory, cardinals, ordinals

Let $\alpha$ be an ordinal number. How can I show that every subset $x$ of $\alpha$ has either the same cardinality as $\alpha$ or there exists an cardinal number $\beta$ such that $|x|=\beta < |\alpha|$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First prove that if $x\subseteq\alpha$, then there is an ordinal $\beta\leq\alpha$ such that $x$ is order isomorphic to $\beta$ (that is to say, $\beta$ is the order type of $x$).

Then you only need to prove that if $\beta\leq\alpha$, then the cardinality of $\beta$ is at most that of $\alpha$. This should be a fairly easy exercise in applying definitions.

Comment: How do you prove the existence of $\beta$?

Comment: How easy/hard depends on what you already know. For example, if you know that every well-ordered set is isomorphic to a unique ordinal, simply note that $x$ is a well-ordered set, and use the various comparability theorems on well-orders to argue that its order type cannot be larger than $\alpha$ itself. If you do not know that, then prove this by induction on $\alpha$, but this tends to be more complicated since it includes ad-hoc proofs of several other basic theorems on well-orders.

Comment: What does it mean when you say order type of an ordinal is larger than other ordinal? Thanks!

Comment: @2pirsquared: The order type of a well-ordered set is an ordinal. So it's just a statement about comparing two ordinals.

Comment: Hi, I see the existence of $\beta$. But why we have $\beta \leq \alpha$? Thanks!

Comment: @2pirsquared: Since $x$ is a subset of $\alpha$, there is an order embedding of $\beta$ into $\alpha$.

Comment: @2pirsquared: I'm not sure what you're trying to prove.

Comment: Sorry, I just confused myself earlier. I want to show that $\beta $ is a cardinal i.e it's not equinumerous with any other ordinals that's strictly less that it. I feel like I have to do an initial segment argument for that. Am I on the right track? Thanks!

Comment: @2pirsquared: It's not necessarily a cardinal. It's an ordinal. But if $\xi$ is an ordinal, then $|\xi|\leq\xi$. So if $|\beta|\leq\beta<\alpha$, what does it tell you about the cardinality of $\beta$?

Comment: @Asaf Karagila: It's not equinumerous with any other ordinals that's strictly less than it. And we know that $x$ is isomorphic to $\beta$. So $x$ is equinumerous to $ |\beta|$?

Answer (score 0):

Let $\alpha^+$ denote the [Hartogs number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hartogs_number) of $\alpha$, i.e. the least ordinal of greater cardinality than $\alpha$. This concept is well-defined for any set. The Hartogs number of any $x\subseteq\alpha$ is at most $\alpha^+$. If it's exactly $\alpha^+$, $x$ bijects with $\alpha$; if not, $x$ bijects with some lesser ordinal.